# Entity Framework won't save relations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following situation:

```
role.Permissions.Add(permission);
objectContext.SaveChanges();
```

When I now take a look in the relations table Roles_Permissions the newly added permission to the role is not present. It only saves the new relation when I dispose the object context. Am I doing something wrong or does a call to SaveChanges doesn't save changes on relationship sets?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework 4

Comment: That code looks fine. More likely something else is causing a problem. Are you using POCO's or any Custom Object Contexts (or Unit of Work), or you using the standard EF code gen from a DB?

Comment: I'm not using POCO's, I'm using the generated code. The only thing that I've added is some anotations for the validation.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ObjectStateManager - before calling SaveChanges, have a look on the object state manager to get all changes that have a state of Added - it should return just the one item which is that permission object. If it's not in there, something else is wrong. Calling SaveChanges should persist your changes then and there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a transaction.

The changes made are not visible outside the transaction scope untill the transaction is committed.

And the transaction scope is not being committed until the object context is disposed.

Comment: I'm not using a transaction. Is it possible that EF creates a transaction automaticly? If so, can I get the transaction somehow to trigger the commit?

Comment: Check the constructor or the properties of your object context. But you should close your object context as soon as possible, so it is probably not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether they are in the same objectContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that your permission entity is known to your object context by executing the following line of code:

```
objectContext.AddObject("Permissions", permission);
```